# Lightning Aura Component works fine in sandbox but not in Production

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura

We have a generic lighning aura component for Custom Add and Remove Products on Quote and Order object which is being called on an action in lightning . The component works fine in the sandboxes but when deployed to production it sometimes gives an error or sometimes not and shows a blank pop up..

Comment: Hello Shivani, Can you please post more detail about your component and error? It will be good if you can share code as well.

Answer (score 0):

My component is build to add line items for quote and order objects ...
[image: Error Image]